# Array in forloop assign defaut session value

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

In Each loop i want default value of array serRefine but it takes old values of serRefine[4] also

```
for (int i = 0; i < rptSize.Items.Count; i++)
{
     Label lblSizeCount = (Label)rptSize.Items[i].FindControl("lblSizeCount");
     HiddenField hfSizeID = (HiddenField)rptSize.Items[i].FindControl("hfSizeID");

     string[] serRefine = (string[])Session["RefineSelection"];
     if (serRefine[4].ToString() != "")
     {
         string Finalsids = "";
         string[] sids = serRefine[4].Split(',');
         for (int j = 0; j < sids.Length; j++)
         {
             if (sids[j].ToString() != hfSizeID.Value)
                 Finalsids += sids[j].ToString() + ",";
         }
         Finalsids += hfSizeID.Value;

         Finalsids = Finalsids.TrimEnd(',');
         serRefine[4] = Finalsids;
     }
     else
         serRefine[4] = hfSizeID.Value;

     lblSizeCount.Text = CommonManager.GetProductCountWithAll(serRefine);
}
```

Comment: what issue you are getting with this code?

Comment: Just guessing: you are databinding the `Repater` in `Page_Load` even on postbacks which causes it to lose all changed values. Use the `IsPostBack`-property of the `Page`.

Comment: but my array values are comming from session

Comment: @PurveshDesai: (If that was an answer to my comment) But you are complaining about the `old values of serRefine[4]` which is set from the hiddenfield.

Comment: yes but should be in next loop the serRefine[4] will be reset from session

Comment: do you update value in hidden field ?

Comment: yes in some of hidden fields are blank, actual problem is string[] serRefine is set from session but if i check the serRefine array in next loop the old values of serRefine[4] is not chnaged as per session

Comment: here is the full code, edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have understood the problem. You want the array to be in the initial state on every iteration. But that's not the case because it is a reference type and you are modifying it in the loop. Here is a simplified sample to reproduce this behaviour:

```
string[] RefineSelection = new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    string[] serRefine = RefineSelection;  // you're not creating a copy but you're referencing the session-array
    string hfSizeID = "foo" + i;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", RefineSelection));
    serRefine[4] = hfSizeID;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", RefineSelection));
}
```

Output will be:

```
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,foo0
A,B,C,D,foo0
A,B,C,D,foo1
A,B,C,D,foo1
A,B,C,D,foo2
```

So the "foo" value from the last iteration will be used before it is changed. As mentioned that's because the array is a reference type and the variable's scope is not the loop itself so the same reference is used.

You could create a clone from the `Session` array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rep.Count; i++)
{
    string[] copy = (string[])RefineSelection.Clone();
    string hfSizeID = "foo" + i;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", copy));
    copy[4] = hfSizeID;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", copy));
}
```

Output:

```
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,foo0
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,foo1
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,foo2
```